# expressjs helmet cps issue with fonts

Tags: node.js, express, content-security-policy, helmet.js

I've added helmet capability to set CPS, however there is an issue with the fonts. A simple example is as follows:

However, it loads all the assets correctly except the Font it complains about.

**sample.css**

```
src: url("/assets/fonts/font.eot")
```

**Example.com**

```
app.use(csp({
    directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        imgSrc: ["'self'"],
        fontSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        sandbox: ['allow-forms', 'allow-scripts'],
        reportUri: '/report-violation',
        objectSrc: [],
    },
    reportOnly: false,
    setAllHeaders: false,
    disableAndroid: false,
    browserSniff: true
}));
```

and in the browser it gives me this error message for the font

```
Font from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

am i missing something to make the font work inside the browser?

In express I have made sure to make the public and assets file are set correctly. (everything from assets works fine).

```
app.use("/assets", express.static(__dirname + "/assets"));
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Comment: what is `__dirname` in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Its a CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) issue, the example I had came from a query on the end of the eot file, e.g. like in font-awesome's [css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.css) because the css was using the

```
src: url(...)
```

instead of

```
src: local(...)
```

If it fails to find the query string, e.g. ?v=4.6.1, which it did, it will make queries to locate that, engaging the CORS issue.

[Some info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) on @font-face from MDN specifically calls out this issue:

> Web fonts are subject to the same domain restriction (font files must be on the same domain as the page using them), unless HTTP access controls are used to relax this restriction.

[MDN CORS info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) that is linked from that documentation.

So either use the local keyword, and error queries fail silently, or you can open up CORS with express using something like this from the [Manning website](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html):

`app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});`

but as you're using CSP, you'll want to dig in to how to lock that CORS header down even further, I'd think?